# NullPointerException when change fragment and using callback

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, callback

I have one problem with changing Fragments, I use spinner in action bar to do this, and sometimes button in alertdiaolog. And when I push the button I have NullPointerException.
This is my code of interface Callback:

```
public interface Callback {
    public void load(String name);
}
```

And this code of my first fragment, I use spinner in onCreateOptiontMenu:

```
private Callback callback;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d("TAG", "onAttach");
        try {
        callback = (Callback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement interface");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callback = null;
    }

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflate) {
        menu.clear();
        inflate.inflate(R.menu.kfu, menu);
        spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_spinner).getActionView()
                .findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_change_map);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                .getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d("POSITION", "Position is = "+position);
                switch (position) {
                case 1: 
                    if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("VKNews")) {
                //      Log.d("Tag", callback.toString()+" "+ (callback == null) + " " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        callback.load("VKNews"); //305 line
                    }   
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }
```

In second fragment I use spinner and sometimes button to change fragment:

```
private Callback callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        Log.d("TAG", "onAttach");
        try {
        callback = (Callback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement interface");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callback = null;
    }

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
if ((firstrun) || (account.access_token == null)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle("Авторизация")
                    .setMessage(
                            "для просмотра новостей необходимо авторизоваться.")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Авторизоваться",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    editor1.putInt("isVk", 1).commit();
                                    editor1.apply();
                                    startLoginActivity();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {           
                                    editor1.putInt("isVk", 0).commit();
                                    editor1.apply();
                                    Log.d("TAG", callback.toString());
                                    callback.load("KFUNews");
                                    Log.d("CHANGE", "change working");
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            // Save the state
            getActivity()
                    .getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",
                            getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    .putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        }
...
}


public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflate) {
        if (account.access_token != null || isChangedStat) {
            inflate.inflate(R.menu.vk, menu);
            spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_spinner1).getActionView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_change_map);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                    .getBaseContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Log.d("POSITION", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("KFUNews")) {
                            callback.load("KFUNews");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        } else {
            inflate.inflate(R.menu.vk1, menu);
            spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_spinner1).getActionView()
                    .findViewById(R.id.actionbar_spinner_change_map);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                    .getBaseContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, actions);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Log.d("POSITION", "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("KFUNews")) {
                            callback.load("KFUNews");
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
    }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflate);
    }
```

I have nullpointer at first fragment at 305 line this callback.load("VKNews");

This is my log:

```
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at ru.fosslabs.mobilestudent.fragment.KFUFragment$3.onItemSelected(KFUFragment.java:305)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:892)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:860)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-01 15:34:58.532: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my Activity:

```
public class GeneralActivity extends Activity implements Callback {
...
    @Override
    public void load(String name) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        Log.d("TAG", "transaction = " + transaction + " "
                + (transaction == null));
        if (name.equals("KFUNews")) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.general_fragment, kfu);
            transaction.commit();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.general_fragment, vkfrag);
            transaction.commit();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: it doesn't work on Android 4.2.2 and 4.3, 4.4**

Comment: Does your activity implement Callback interface?

Comment: yes.
public class GeneralActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

Answer (score 0):

The activity is probably implementing the wrong interface. Callback is the name of the numerous interfaces. Make sure you use a unique name for your interface or change your `GeneralActivity extends Activity implements Callback`

to

`GeneralActivity extends Activity implements ru.fosslabs.mobilestudent.fragment.KFUFragment.Callback`

Answer (score -1):

Three possibilities:

1. the onAttach() is not called before the event fires, and `callback` is never set.
2. onAttach() is called, but with a null value for `activity`
3. detach() is called at some point before the event